# New Facebook Login with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i  have implemented many code in my project.I am not able to identify the issue.
Which URL i need to use with this Everytime i get this error.

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

put mu redirect and return URL string as - "http:// localhost / facebook/"

Same string i put in my FB App Account as "Site URL" : same line as above

I know this is repeated question but ...

Comment: you need to setup your facebook app to allow url from localhost

Comment: Don't forget to reset your app secret if you've provided the real one.

Comment: hmmm... secret code. that seems like a good thing to show everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook login do not work locally, also you need to mention the URL in you facebook APP Setting

Go through following link for more details:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-users-with-facebook-connect--net-12302

Answer (score 1):

Canvas URL should be

```
http://localhost/facebook/
```

without spaces or otherwise.
In App Domains you should also add

```
localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **IP Address** i.e. `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`

and one more thing you should check .i.e you need to define `redirect_url` along with your config and which is must be same as `site_url` you define in your facebook app

Comment: NO success ..same result

Comment: Than probably the Facebook has changes the policy because sometime ago my Like button is not working in my `localhost` and than i try to upload it on live server and its works so, Now they don't accept any request from `localhost`. So, Just try to do this from your live server and don't forget to change `site_url` in your facebook app when you are testing it from live server.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://subhra.me/using-facebook-php-sdk-3-codeigniter-2-1/
This a very simple tutorial.